# Restrict Multiple form edit in AngularJS Single Page application

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I'm developing an SPA in angularjs consisting of five form sections in one page. Each of the forms can be edited and saved individually. I need to restrict editing forms one at a time. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You could do this with mixing ng-focus and ng-class?

Comment: You can use `ng-hide` and `ng-show`. If one form is in editing mode you can hide other forms.

Comment: @Rohit, you meant, using `ng-hide` and `ng-show` using a global variable?

Comment: @MaanusIndov Yes..i think it will work.

Comment: If it fails i could create a code example also :)

Comment: If yes, i could add a watch to global variable, say X.While editing a form, set x false and call apply, also trigger cancel form  edit on other forms. Any better methods than this one?

Comment: One doubt along with. Will the global variable cause the current editing form to hide?